# Netsuite - Writing a Saved Search Formula for Date Created within last hour

Tags: sql, date, time, formula, netsuite

I am trying to write a formula that will return the Records for a list of transactions when the Date is within the last 30 minutes.

Something like this - Obviously the code below is very much not going to work but this is the result I am trying to achieve.

```
CASE WHEN SYSDATE - {Datecreated} IS WITHIN 30 MINUTES THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Please edit the tags of your question to indicate the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 7):

Netsuite uses PL/SQL semantics for formula fields and date arithmetic in formulas.

if you use a Formula (Numeric) criteria you can do `{now} - {datecreated}` <= .020833

where days are integer values and fractions of a day are fractions of 24 hours so `.5/24 = .020833`

Comment: First, I'm so happy I found answer here, this solve my issue!! Second, may I know how to get .0625 from .5/24...? I'm trying to figure out the logic...

Comment: Thanks for asking. It looks like a fumble on the keyboard. The example has been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The method I use converts the difference (a decimal where 1 represents 24 hours) into hours or minutes:

### Hours

Criteria Formula:  `({now} - {datecreated}) * 24`

Formula (Numeric):  `is less than or equal to`

Value:  `0.5`

### Minutes

Criteria Formula:  `({now} - {datecreated}) * 24 * 60`

Formula (Numeric):  `is less than or equal to`

Value:  `30`